# Removing numbers from the first part of an array

Tags: python

I've been trying to remove numbers from the first part of my array, but I can't seem to find the right order to do it. In my logic, I should separate the part of the array that I need to extract the numbers and then use append to make the array complete again.

In my code, I would receive an input similar to:

```
["1518969489sunflower_of_the_year", 15, 8.99, 55,85]
```

My output must be:

```
["sunflower of the year", 15, 8.99, 55,85]
```

I've tried to do something like this, but I can't seem to find the right order to separate the letters and the _. Any input is very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
def extract_number (array):

array.split ("_")
```

####After removing the _, I can't seem to find a solution to separate the number from the word.

`array.pop (0)` #### After separating the numbers, I would delete with .pop.

Any input is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Example: `" ".join("I_am_the_walrus".split("_"))` => `"I am the walrus"`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
ls = ["1518969489sunflower_of_the_year", 15, 8.99, 55,85]

count = 0
for i in ls:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        new_num = ''.join([j for j in i if not j.isdigit()]).replace("_", " ")
        ls.pop(count)
        ls.insert(count,new_num)
    count+=1
print(ls)
```

Output

```
['sunflower of the year', 15, 8.99, 55, 85]
```

Comment: Nitpick, but instead of `isinstance`, perhaps catching a `ValueError` with `int(i)` is more Pythonic. Python is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.